# switching to Console in R

Tags: r, console, command

Working with R I am looking for a command switching to Console, but not closing any graphic device.
That is I am looking for something like

```
graphics.off()
```

but not closing, just inactivating all available graphic devices.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in Windows you can just do 'ctrl+tab' and it will do the switch.

Comment: By "graphic devices", you mean windows with plots?

Comment: yes, I am actually looking for a command doing the same as typing 'ctrl+tab'

Comment: yes, "graphic devices" = "windows with plots".

Comment: Because png, bmp,... are also graphics devices.